# referencing an object literal to set innerHTML in a span element javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a small data store of quotes like this:

```
let quotes = [{
   quote: "Search others for their virtues, thyself for thy vices.",
   source: "Benjamin Franklin",
   citation: "Poor Richard\'s Almanac",
   category: "ethics",
   year: ''
 }, {
   quote: "He who has courage despises the future.",
   source: "Napoleon Bonaparte",
   citation: '',
   category: "boldness",
   year: ''
}
]
```

I am running a simple javascript function to change the html based on the data store with this:

```
const getRandomQuote = () => {
    let quoteShownArr = [];
    let quoteIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length) + 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
      if (quoteIndex === i) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML = quotes[i].quote;
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[1].innerHTML = quotes[i].source;
          let citation = quotes[i].citation;
          if(citation) {
          console.log(citation);
          document.getElementById("citation").innerHTML = quotes[i].citation;
        }
          document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = quotes[i].year;
      }
    }
  }
  getRandomQuote();
```

All the html elements are being updated except for my citation and year, which are span elements.  I get the following error:
TypeError: "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at getRandomQuote" But the exact value consoles easily.  How is this not changing the element??
Thanks.
HTML added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random Quotes</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="quote-box">
      <p class="quote">You can do anything but not everything</p>
      <p class="source">David Allen<span class="citation" id="citation">Making It All Work</span><span class="year" id="year">2009</span></p>
    </div>
    <button id="loadQuote">Show another quote</button>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You post HTML?

Comment: share your html code. are you sure that span has id called citation?

Comment: html added - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[1].innerHTML = quotes[i].source;
```

you set the inner html to the source text, removing all other html content e.G your spans, this is why they are `null` because they dont exist anymore